# What's the dual graph of the plane graph of order 2 and size 0?

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the plane graph consisting of 2 vertices and no edges. It has one face and no edge, so its dual is the trivial graph. On the other hand, it has two vertices, so its dual should have two faces-- yet the trivial graph has only one face.

What is wrong with my understanding/argument?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a one to one correspondence between the faces of the dual and the vertices of the original graph in general: this is only true when our original graph is connected.

To see this, let e*= #edges in dual, f*= #faces in dual, v*= #vertices in dual, and e,f,v be the number of edges/faces/vertices respectively in out original graph.
In general, we see that e=e* and v*=f by definition.

Then, since every dual graph is both planar and connected, we have: 
v*-e*+f*=2
which implies
f*=2-v*+e*=2-f+e.
For this to equal the number of vertices in our original graph, we would require:
2-f+e=v, ie v-e+f=2, or for our original graph to be connected. Since the graph with two vertices and no edges is not connected, we cannot make this correspondence.